# BootstrapVue access b-table row data in slot template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I have a delete button on each row and I need to get `log_id` from items to pass to function `deleteLog`.  That function always alerts `log_id` is `undefined`.

How can I pass `log_id` to the function `deleteLog` without `undefined`?

```html
<template>
    <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields">
        <template v-slot:cell(Delete)>
            <b-button variant="danger" v-on:click="deleteLog(log_id)">Delete</b-button>
        </template>
    </b-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            fields: ['Year', 'Month', 'Round', 'Name', 'Delete', 'log_id'],
            items: []
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the row data and its `log_id` through the slot data:

```html
<b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields">
    <template v-slot:cell(Delete)="data"> <!-- `data` -->
        <b-button variant="danger" v-on:click="deleteLog(data.item.log_id)">Delete</b-button>
    </template>
</b-table>
```

Here's another syntax, [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) the slot data:

```html
<b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields">
    <template v-slot:cell(Delete)="{ item }"> <!-- `item` -->
      <b-button variant="danger" v-on:click="deleteLog(item.log_id)">Delete</b-button>
    </template>
</b-table>
```